# Azure Change Feed Support and multiple local clients

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a scenario where multiple clients would like to get updates from Document Db inserts, but they are not available online all the time.

Example: Suppose there are three clients registered with the system, but only one is online at present time. When the online client inserts/updates a document, we want the offline client(s) on wakes up to go look at change feed and update itself independently.

Now is there a way for each client to maintain it's own feed to the same partition (when they were last synced) and get the changes when the come online based on last sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using change feed, you use continuation token per partition. Change feed continuation tokens do not expire, thus you can continue from any point. Each client can keep its own continuation token and read changes as needed/wakes up, this essentially means that each client can keep its own feed for each partition.

Comment: Does that mean that a client keeping their continuation token can work on same partition and based on last sync, it will fetch only those elements? Do  you know if there is a special query for it or checkpoints will be required?

Comment: From server point of view, checkpoints are not required, but the client can checkpoint just in case it crashes/etc. Multiple clients can work on same partition but it's not guaranteed that they will get exactly same changes because intermediate versions are not preserved.

Comment: For instance, let's say there are 2 clients, 1 partition and 1 document. Time points: t1 < t1'< t2 < t2' < t3 < t3'. The document was modified at t1, t2, t3, versions v1, v2, v3.
Both clients read change feed at t1' and saved continuation. Then clientA read change feed at t2' while clientB was sleeping. Then both clients read at t3'. Now both clients have same most recent version of the doc, i.e. v3. But clientA went thought 3 changes, while clientB - only 2.

Comment: In our case we only care about the latest version and not worry about multiple transitions.